# Selecting covariates for Ancova

Tags: ancova, predictor

I'm running ANCOVA to measure if changes made to a Web Site have been effective or not.
The web pages have been clustered into different issues.

**Test Group** : Set of URLs pertaining to an issue which has one or more URL that has changed
**Control Group**: Similar issues.

The test & control group would be the groups in ANCOVA

The Visits to the group is the DV.
I want to run the framework on a week before & after the date of change.

I want to control for external factors causing visits to spike.

How do I decide what to use as a co-variate?
I was thinking of page views, which is highly correlated with Visits, but is also affected by experimental manipulation (changes on the web)

Thanks